C# WinForms databound ComboBox with null SelectedValue not updating to blank in .NET 8
I have a C# Winforms  application in .NET Framework 4 and I have updaded it to .NET 8. It is an application that binds to a SQL Server database and several forms perform CRUD operations. All the fields in the database are NOT NULL.
After the upgrade, all forms with ComboBox controls that are bound to DataTables with the SelectedValue property are having an unexpected behaviour: If the ComboBox has a value selected and the users deletes the value in the control (focusing on the control, selecting the text and pressing Backspace or Delete in the Keyboard), which automatically changes the value of SelectedValue to null, no update is done in the column of the DataRow associated to the current record being edited with the BindingSource.
The code generated by IntelliSense in VS2022 for the ComboBox is the following:
        companiaPredeter.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", usersBindingSource, "CompaniaPredeterminada", true));
        companiaPredeter.DataSource = companyBindingSource;
        companiaPredeter.DisplayMember = "Name";
        companiaPredeter.FormattingEnabled = true;
        companiaPredeter.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(111, 255);
        companiaPredeter.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
        companiaPredeter.Name = "companiaPredeter";
        companiaPredeter.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(214, 23);
        companiaPredeter.TabIndex = 9;
        companiaPredeter.ValueMember = "CompanyId";

It is expected that the value of the column would be set to an empty string when a users deletes the content of the control, as happens in .NET Framework 4.0. As there are several hundred fields in this condition, what can I do to fix this in an automated and efficient way?

Can you show the code related to the data Biding, describe what the users deletes the value in the control means, in practice (since you're referring to a ComboBox), and what internally setting SelectedValue = null also means, in practice (what code does that, when and based on what conditions) -- It's assumed you're only using DataTables, not class models (because of what you said, correct this assumption otherwise)

@Jimi I have updated the question, addressing your questions. Please let me know if this makes my problem clearer. Thanks in advance!

It looks like the Column of the destination DataTable (connected to the Binding) is a ValueType. A ValueType's null value must be DbNull.Value. So, when you see that SelectedValue changes to null, you have to convert null to DbNull.Value (assigning it to the SelectedValue Property). You could handle the TextChanged event for that (as a simple workaround / test case), since a SelectedValue change is not (IIRC) notified when the text is deleted, except in a Validation event (e.g., when Focus changes)

It's assumed that the Column in the DataTable is configured to accept DBNull.Value as a possible value. The Binding's DataSourceNullValue and NullValue are configured to handle this already

@Jimi As stated, all columns in the database are NOT NULL. The DataTables are defined in a DataSet object (contained in XSD files). All columnas are indeed ValueTypes and are set to AllowDBNull = false by default when a TableAdapter is added to the DataSet file. So, using DBNull.Value is not feasible, as they would be rejected upon validation.

@Jimi you mention "since a SelectedValue change is not (IIRC) notified when the text is deleted, except in a Validation event (e.g., when Focus changes)". Is this done automatically? As I have tested deleting the content and losing focus, but still the change is not notified to the DataRow.

The Value change, in the Control, is notified (BTW, the way you have setup the Binding, the property change notification is OnValidation, not OnPropertyChanged). What matters is that, when you delete the text, the SelectedValue is set to null, which is not compatible with the DataTable's specifications. It needs to be DBNull.Value, hence my previous comments. As the whole thing is setup right now, you  have to set SelectedValue to DBNull.Value yourself when you the text is deleted (i.e., in the TextChanged handler). Then the DataTable can be updated
